# Ocaml CSV to Float List

Tags: csv, ocaml

I'm looking for the easiest way to turn a CSV file (of floats) into a float list. I'm not well acquainted with reading files in general in Ocaml, so I'm not sure what this sort of function entails.

Any help or direction is appreciated :)

EDIT: I'd prefer not to use a third party CSV library unless I absolutely have to.

Answer (score 3):

https://forge.ocamlcore.org/projects/csv/

Comment: So, did you type "Ocaml CSV" into Google by any chance?

Comment: Yes, actually I'm hoping to solve this problem without using a 3rd party library. Because I only need this one function I didn't think it would be worth including someone else's library in my project.

Comment: Then you should look at the 3rd party library to learn how it's done.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't want to include a [third-party library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261485/ocaml-csv-to-float-list/10261498#10261498), and your CSV files are simply formatted with no quotes or embedded commas, you can parse them easily with standard library functions. Use `read_line` in a loop or in a recursive function to read each line in turn. To split each line, call `Str.split_delim` (link your program with `str.cma` or `str.cmxa`). Call `float_of_string` to parse each column into a float.

```
let comma = Str.regexp ","
let parse_line line = List.map float_of_string (Str.split_delim comma line)
```

Note that this will break if your fields contain quotes. It would be easy to strip quotes at the beginning and at the end of each element of the list returned by `split_delim`. However, if there are embedded commas, you need a proper CSV parser. You may have embedded commas if your data was produced by a localized program in a French locale — French uses commas as the decimal separator (e.g. English `3.14159`, French `3,14159`). Writing floating point data with commas instead of dots isn't a good idea, but it's something you might encounter (some spreadsheet CSV exports, for example). If your data comes out of a Fortran program, you should be fine.

Comment: And that's going to break as soon as there is a field containing a comma, or a quoted field.

Comment: I've seen too much csv reading code that assumed that there will be no quotes etc, but that never lasted for long.